# Get the Last Two Non-Null Values for a column in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Right now, I have a select statement that returns this result set:

```
|  date  | id  | price |
+--------+-----+-------+
| Jan 01 | XYZ | 5.00  |
| Jan 02 | XYZ | NULL  |
| Jan 03 | XYZ | NULL  |
| Jan 06 | XYZ | NULL  |
| Jan 07 | XYZ | 3.00  |
| Jan 08 | XYZ | NULL  |
```

The problem is that I want to get the last known price for the product with the id of `XYZ` in the row if the value is `NULL`, but only to grab this if it is within two days. So for `Jan 02` & `Jan 03` I'd like to see the value from `Jan 01`, but not for `Jan 06`.

Here's what I mean:

```
|  date  | id  | price |
+--------+-----+-------+
| Jan 01 | XYZ | 5.00  |
| Jan 02 | XYZ | 5.00  | (Jan 01)
| Jan 03 | XYZ | 5.00  | (Jan 01)
| Jan 06 | XYZ | NULL  | << Stays NULL
| Jan 07 | XYZ | 3.00  |
| Jan 08 | XYZ | 3.00  | (Jan 07)
```

Here's the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.catalogue
(
  [date] DATE NOT NULL ,
  [id] VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL ,
  [price] FLOAT
)
```

And the Sample Data:

```
INSERT  INTO dbo.catalogue
    ( [date], [id], [price] )
VALUES  
    ( '2015-01-01', 'XYZ', 5.00 ),
    ( '2015-01-02', 'XYZ', NULL ),
    ( '2015-01-03', 'XYZ', NULL ),
    ( '2015-01-06', 'XYZ', NULL ),
    ( '2015-01-07', 'XYZ', 3.00 ),
    ( '2015-01-08', 'XYZ', NULL )
```

**Edit**: Also, I should mention that this is within a stored procedure's subquery, so performance will definitely matter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't the id column also NULL in the missing date rows?

Comment: @Amit the query I gave as an example was incorrect. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What version of sql server? It would be a lot easier if you posted ddl and sample data in a consumable format so we can build a query against it.

Comment: @SeanLange updated for version.

Comment: @Amit checking the documentation for Lag - I think that might be exactly what I'm looking for, thanks.

Comment: I removed that comment since your using v2008

Comment: @Amit oh man that's disappointing

Comment: Yeah with 2008 this is a little more challenging but still feasible. Post some ddl and we can knock this out pretty quickly.

Comment: Set the first result set as a CTE with a `ROW_NUMBER()`, then select the CTE and join it twice with row-1 & row-2. Then `COALESCE`...

Comment: DDL = data definition language (create table/object scripts.
DML = data manipulation language (CRUD)
Here is an excellent article on this. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @Gene the problem is that I need the last valid price in that row for that date. Otherwise, your suggestion would accomplish the same thing

Comment: @SeanLange is there anything more that you need past the table definition?

Comment: Would make it easier on us if the sample data was inserts. If you can't do it I will try to soon.

Comment: @SeanLange I'll whip up some sample data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution using `APPLY`:

```
SELECT  
    c.[date],
    c.id,
    price = ISNULL(c.price, x.price)
FROM dbo.catalogue c
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 price
    FROM dbo.catalogue
    WHERE 
        DATEDIFF(DAY, [date], c.[date]) <= 2
        AND c.[date] > [date]
        AND id = c.id
    ORDER BY date DESC
)x
```

Answer (score 2):

If you were using 2012+ this would be a bit easier using LAG but you can do this with a cte in 2008. Thank you for posting consumable ddl and sample data. That makes this a lot easier.

Here is one way to do this.

```
with cte as
(
    select *
        , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by date) as RowNum
    from catalogue
)

select c.date
    , c.id
    , isnull(case when DATEDIFF(day, c2.date, c.date) <= 2 
        then 
        (
            select MAX(price) from cte c3 
            where c3.RowNum >= c2.RowNum - 1
        )
        end, c.price) as NewPrice
from cte c
left join cte c2 on c2.RowNum = c.RowNum - 1
```

Comment: could you post an answer using Lag? I think we may upgrade our servers soon and I'll definitely come back to try using Lag